# UVs don't display on one specific part of the model

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

The UVS on the foot for my model display no texture. It is just flat gray. It should look half blue half gray from where the UVs are in the texture. If I move them they are still just gray. I tried duplicating them, recalculating normals, adding more faces. But nothing will get the faces to display the texture. I'm using Blender and Substance Painter the UVs were auto unwrapped by Substance and the foot is a duplicated and modified version of the hand. Any ideas to get the texture to display?

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the whole UV map?
And if you could post another screenshot with sync selection on, and select the feet in the mesh, it could also be useful.

Comment: Alexandre Marcati I actually found the problem there were two materials on the model. One of them on the foot. When I deleted the second one the foot started displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra material on the foot. Once I deleted that material the texture then displayed correctly.